# undefined method `first_name=' Rspec + Factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I've been building my application and I'm now ready to start testing. I have Factory girl defined in seeds.rb but as I'm running tests I've also defined the tests in the usual place `/spec/factories.rb` for Rspec.

However my first tests fails with the following error.

`user_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  it "should have valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.build(:user1).should be_valid
  end
end
```

Error returned:

```
Failures:

  1) User should have valid factory
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.build(:user1).should be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `first_name=' for #<User:0x000000061410f8>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.05459 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:4 # User should have valid factory

Randomized with seed 29084
```

`spec/factories.rb`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin1, class: User do
    first_name "admin"
    last_name "minstrator"
    password "admin1234"
    profile_name "profilename"
    email "admin@admin.com"
    password_confirmation "admin1234"
    admin true
    end

    factory :user1, class: User do
    first_name "user2"
    last_name "man2"
    password "user1234"
    profile_name "profilename"
    email "user2@user.com"
    password_confirmation "user1234"
    admin false
    end

  end
```

It works fine when using the data on development in my seed.rb but now I've started testing using Rspec it has all gone wrong.

What am I doing incorrectly here. I'm not a huge fan of testing at the moment but I need to improve my skill set here as I know it can be extremely useful for web applications.

You help is greatly appreciated, please let me know if you need anymore info.

Answer (score 1):

If your code works in development, but not in test, my guess is that your test copy of the database is not in sync. Try running `rake db:test:prepare` or `rake db:test:clone` and run your specs again.

> Note:
>
> `db:test:clone` isn't required in Rails 4.2.0 `'WARNING: db:test:clone is deprecated.` The Rails test helper now maintains your test schema automatically, see the release notes for details.')

Comment: Nope that doesn't work but when I try rake db:reset I get the same error for undefined method first_name

Comment: can you post your `schema.rb`

Comment: Thanks Scott. This issue has been hitting me over and over. Wasn't til you mentioned the databases might not be in sync that I jumped into `rails console -e test` and ran `User` to see my 'first_name' field wasn't there. Ran your suggested answer and all fixed! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here was that one of my migrations was missing and because it didn't have users first_name in the model there was nothing defined.

A big tip to all newbies, never ever ever delete any of your migrations.

As Homer Simpson quite rightly said "D'oh"